# Do these two phrases mean something different?

Tags: sentence-translation, word-usage

I need assistance in correctly identifying which statement makes sense:

*Nostrae Cor Jesu Fons Sapientiae* or *Nostrae Cor Iesu Fons Sapientiae*

There is a debate that the second statement is the correct one but I am not sure. Note that the statement is used in the logo for my institution: Sacred Heart Junior College.

[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the community! What did you want either of those phrases to mean? It will help to know what it is you are trying to convey in Latin.

Comment: @Adam The statement should be related to the scared heart of jesus but I honestly do not know which is the correct one or whether the statements make sense. Consequently since I do not know latin I cannot say which is correct.

Comment: There's no grammatical difference between the two statements; the second one just uses an _I_ for the same consonant that is a _J_ in the first. It's really just a stylistic choice.

Comment: @Adam So `Jesu` and `Iesu` mean the same thing?

Comment: Yes! :) There is no _J_ in classical Latin, but one was substituted in later to make it easier to distinguish when an _I_ is a consonant or a vowel.

Comment: @Adam Can you help correctly translate it? I want to understand what it means.

Comment: You can find the meaning on the Wikipedia entry for [Sacred Heart College](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_Heart_College,_Cayo):  _Our Sacred Heart of Jesus, source of all our wisdom_

Answer (score 6):

First, as noted in the comments, some people like to use the letter J when writing Latin, others don't (and just write I instead). There's a distinction, as seen in pairs like **J**ulius vs **I**ulus, but the Romans didn't distinguish them in writing and it seldom creates actual ambiguity. So there's no difference in meaning between the two.

Literally, that meaning is "Heart of Jesus, Font of Our Wisdom". If I were writing this, I would rearrange the words and say *Cor Jesu Fons **Sapientiae Nostrae***, putting "our" next to "wisdom", but this way isn't incorrect: Latin word order is fairly free, so the words can be rearranged to some extent to sound better.

Comment: there's an interesting contrast between the i/j distinction and the u/v distinction. In both cases. Only one letter form was used in Classical Latin, and the other developed from it in the Middle Ages. One represents a consonant, and the other a vowel. And yet, solely using v is almost unheard of in modern printed texts, whilst it's easy to find modern printed texts that only use i

Comment: @Tristan I think the main difference is that modern readers are familiar with I as a vowel, but not with V (so you can still find editions that only use U for both consonant and vowel). But agreed, it's strange how the U/V distinction has caught on more thoroughly than the I/J one.

Comment: oh yeah, people are obviously more familiar with I as a vowel, but many people are not familiar with use of I as a consonant. So the situation with I/J is reversed from the U/V situation, in the former the one that became the vowel is the original form, in the latter it's the one that became the consonant